# password and ip restriction in htaccess

Tags: permissions, .htaccess

I am learning how to use htaccess.

1. First I want to try how to set up username and password for the
   following directory `~/public_html/55/m`:

   ```
   ~/public_html/55/m$ ls -la
   total 24
   drwxr-xr-x 2 tim Domain^Users 4096 2011-12-16 21:39 .
   drwxr-xr-x 3 tim Domain^Users 4096 2011-12-16 21:42 ..
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tim Domain^Users  271 2011-12-16 21:26 .htaccess
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tim Domain^Users    8 2011-12-16 21:39 .htpasswd
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tim Domain^Users  884 2011-12-16 20:02 index.html
   ```

   I manually created two text files: `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.
   Their contents are

   ```
   ~/public_html/55/m$ cat .htaccess
   AuthUserFile /home/WIN/local/WIN/tim/public_html/55/m/.htpasswd
   AuthGroupFile /dev/null
   AuthName EnterPassword
   AuthType Basic

   Require valid-user

   ~/public_html/55/m$ cat .htpasswd
   tim:123
   ```

   But I can access the webpage without being asked to provide username
   and password. I wonder why?
2. Second I want to try how to restrict the ip range to access
   `~/public_html/55/n`

   ```
   ~/public_html/55/n$ ls -la
   total 16
   drwxr-xr-x 2 tim Domain^Users 4096 2011-12-16 21:54 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 tim Domain^Users 4096 2011-12-16 21:53 ..
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tim Domain^Users  292 2011-12-16 21:53 .htaccess
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 tim Domain^Users  884 2011-12-16 21:53 index.html
   ```

   where I created manually the text file `.htaccess` whose content is:

   ```
   ~/public_html/55/n$ cat .htaccess 
   AuthUserFile /dev/null
   AuthGroupFile /dev/null
   AuthName AllowFromBlah
   AuthType Basic

   <limit GET>
   order  deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from xxx.edu
   </Limit>
   ```

   But I can access the webpage from outside the specified ip range
   `xxx.edu`. I wonder why?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe .htaccess files for those directories are simply ignored using the `AllowOverride` directive in the virtual host configuration. From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride:

> When this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are
>   completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to
>   read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

EDIT: On Ubuntu configuration is based in `/etc/apache2`, other systems have their configuration based in `/etc/httpd` or another directory.  The Ubuntu configuration for user home directories is handled by `mods-available/userdir.conf` which is enabled when linked into `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.  It specifies home directories as `/home/*/public_html`.  The `php4.conf` also references the same directories.

Comment: Thanks! My home address is `/home/WIN/local/WIN/tim`, and I know for some users whose home addresses are under `/home/`, .htaccess files work for their webpages. I wonder how this difference is possible or my setups are not correct?

Comment: Yes it may be an issue.  `AllowOverride` may not be configured for your directory.  It can be restricted to certain directory paths.

Comment: S19N and @BillThor: Thanks! Where can I find the "virtual host configuration" on the server where the AllowOverride directive may possibly is used?

Comment: If you have access to the complete filesystem have a look under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

Comment: Thanks, S19N! There is no `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` on the server but there is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. In the latter, I found three files containing `AllowOverride`: `000-default`,  `mailman` and `ssl`. In both `000-default` and `ssl` (are they both relevant?), `AllowOverride none` is specified for the following directories: `/`,`/var/www`, `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` , `/usr/share/doc/`. So how does `.htaccess` work for users whose home addresses under /home/, and not for `/home/WIN/local/WIN/tim`, given that they are not mentioned in the two files?

Comment: The .htaccess seems correct, I haven't got any suggestions left other than submitting your .htaccess to your sysadmin of tech support staff...